# What is Asset, and key-value pair in Asset in Hyperledger fabric?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

What is asset and how and where the value of asset is defined, what is key-value pair in Asset ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the asset definition here : [Readthedocs Assets](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fabric_model.html#assets)

Fabric Composer let you define asset easily : [Hyperledger Composer Modeling Language](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/cto_language.html)